# How to include file downloads with Application Insights

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

I've installed the default Application Insights (the js snippet with key) on my webapp and it's working well for everything apart from one of the end results which is a PDF download. I do process the request and return the PDF from an MVC5 controller if it makes any difference in this situation.

Is there any way I can track this file in the same way? And if not what's the best way to use AI to track users across the 'normal' pages and the PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless you create some kind of "wrapper" html+javascript page that loads the pdf, the JavaScript sdk+snippet wouldn't work here.

you'd add the application insights web sdk nuget packages/etc to your controller side (or enable status monitor on that website if you're on azure), and use the same ikey in the configuration there.

then you'd get both server side requests/dependencies/exceptions/traces AND client side pageviews/dependencies/exceptions/traces

Comment: do you have any code examples for serverside tracking? I'm specifically looking for how to track whether an authenticated user downloaded a file from the portal or not. 
Love,
Tim

Comment: the most comprehensive is probably https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net, once you have things hooked up you can use `TelemetryClient` to send whatever telemetry you want from wherever.